# Omit mongoose to return document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to know how can I achieve not to return anything from a `mongoose.save()` operation.

Lets say I want to update a document, but want to keep schema validations, so I can't use [Model.update](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update).

Why? By default mongoose returns the whole document, and if that is a complicated one it will take some time while `JSON.parse` runs. I know about `.lean(), .select()` but i was wondering if its possible to omit any response at all.

```
myModel
  .save()
  .then(function(model) {
    // i want the model to be undefined, null, {} or something like this
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you enable Mongoose debug logging with `mongoose.set('debug', true);` you'll see that the `save` operation is executed as a native driver `update` which doesn't return the updated document so there's nothing to parse anyway.

What `myModel.save` is passing to the callback is just the same `myModel` object you called it on.

So the following will log `true`:

```
myModel
  .save()
  .then(function(model) {
    console.log(model === myModel);
  });
```

So it's not something you need to worry about disabling somehow.